# Custom report for SpecFlow

Tags: xslt, specflow

We're using Specflow with NUnit for our executable specifications. We're very impressed by specflow and the nice VS integration. We've also setup our build server (TeamCity) to run the specs and generate a "test execution report".

However, we're not so impressed by the report generated by specflow. There's an option to specify a [custom xslt for the report generator](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting), but we're not that fluent in xslt...

So my question is; Has anyone made any custom reports for the specflow report generator that they want to share here?

Comment: What is it about the report that doesn't meet your needs?  I run the Tests through NUnit and utilized the xml output to generate a report from SpecFlow and that works well enough for us to know what tests fail and details.

Comment: The biggest issue is the lack of ordering of the tests based on namespaces. The tests are ordered alphabetically, but that doesn't make much sense. Grouping based on namespace and/or tags would have made the reports easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I wrote one for myself. Here you can find a custom HTML report (supports screenshots): https://github.com/koshkarov/html-specflow-report It is configurable.
It supports screenshots.
It saves report data to the path in App.config. It does not require specflow+.
It works based on the specflow hooks. I've created a project with dummy tests, so you can see how it works and what generates. I'll add detailed description soon.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you check out the [Pickles project](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles) that creates a very nice documentation in a format of your choice (HTML, PDF, Word and other is supported).

It can be used via MsBuild, Powershell and via the commandline. And you'll get it easily from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/pickles)

Comment: Sweat! Actually remember reading about Pickles some time ago, but I had forgotten all about it. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I testet Pickles which works fine for generating 'living documentation' based on the feature files, but it doesn't give a good overview of which features pass/fail/pending.

Comment: Hey, that's quite right. Then you might be better off using the SpecFlow.exe and it's reporting capabilities. It's not as pretty but still; http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/specflowexe-and-mstest.html

Answer (score 0):

This post of mine may help you create your own customized report as I have created a sample one here
http://softwarecookie.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/specflow-test-execution-report-enhancement/

Hope that helps